# Convergence of a sequence in finite number of steps

Tags: probability, convergence, probability-inequalities, sequential-analysis

Here is the setup of my problem. It is a sequential problem and there are two possible actions A and B. Now, when either action $A$ or $B$ is taken at the $j$th time point, we observe some outcome say $X_j$.  We want to compare the two averages in batches $k = 1,2,\dots, M$ with each batch having $d_k$ time points. We also decide that out of a total $d_k$ points in the $k$th batch, action A will be taken $m_kd_k$ where $0 < m_k <1$ is the proportion that is chosen apriori and $(1-m_k)d_k$ is the number of times B is the chosen action. Now, we compare the averages of these outcomes for the two actions.
$$  \dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^{d_k} X_j I_j(A)}{m_k d_k} - \dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^{d_k} X_j I_j(B)}{(1-m_k)d_k}> \beta_k - (1)$$ where $I_j(.)$ is the indicator function and $\beta_k <0 $. Now based on if condition (1) holds, we change $m_k$ for the next batch $k+1$. More precisely, let's say we decrease $m_k$ by half if the condition doesn't hold, so 
$$m_{k+1} = \begin{cases}  m_k & \text{with probability} \ p_{k+1}\\
                        \frac{m_k}{2} & \text{with probability} \ 1-p_{k+1}
\end{cases}$$ 
where
$$p_{k+1} = P\left( \dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^{d_k} X_j I_j(A)}{m_k d_k} - \dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^{d_k} X_j I_j(B)}{(1-m_k)d_k}> \beta_k \right)$$
I want to show that $m_k \rightarrow 0$ almost surely in a finite number of batches. We also know that event (1) is highly likely to occur, i.e. $p_k\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$. Then, intuitively it makes sense that with proper choices of $\beta_k$'s, $m_k$ should become very small quickly (because of the exponential decay assumed), I just don't know how to mathematically prove it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: From how you've set up the $m_{k}$, it seems like $m_{k} \geq m_{0} / 2^{k} > 0$ for any $k$. So I'm not sure how you could have $m_{k} \to 0$ if you limit $k$ to some finite set of values. (I'm interpreting "finite number of batches" as only allowing finitely many values of $k$.) Perhaps you can clarify your question further, especially what type of convergence you're looking for with the $m_{k}$?